# Read HTML file from folder and put its content into block of web site using asp.net MVC C#

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, database

I have HTML files placed in an HTML folder of my project. The file name of those HTML files are stored in the field of database. I want to read the contents of each HTML file and put it in a `<div>` on the web page.

This is what I have done successfully with the image path:

```
<img width="135px" src="<%:HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist(HelperClass.Contact.PathProductImages+Model.Item[i].PictureName)%>" alt="<%: Model.Item[i].Name %>"/>
```

It is no problem with the file name of image, but with the content of html file, I have no idea.

Can anyone tell me, how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? It would make the task very easy.

Comment: @JSang: I never use JQuery. Could you show me some code please?

Comment: if you don't know jQuery, it would be better you implement others' suggestions. However, if you still want to go the jQuery way, you can read the jQuery's `load` [api](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText()` or `StreamReader` class methods to read a file from the disk.

For instance, suppose you have `sample.html` files under the `files` folder in the root web-app folder.

```
string path=HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/sample.html");
string content=System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: It produced error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\test.htm'.

Comment: @socheata - That's it. The file you want to read is not found. Please write proper the path/location. If these files are located inside the web-app project then use ~ root operator (see my post).

Comment: @socheata - Please include the code you are trying so far in your post and also show the location of test.htm.

Comment: <%
                            string spec = Model.ItemDetail.HTMLDetail;
                            string path = HelperClass.Contact.PathHtmlDetail + spec;
                        %>
                        
                        <%:HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist(HelperClass.Contact.PathHtmlDetail + spec)%> : This block of code will print the path: http://gg:9090/Product/HtmlDetail/test.htm

Comment: But I have no idea, how can I print this html content out.

Comment: Can you give me some solution?

Comment: @socheata - Download a sample app  - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8842115/MvcApplication4.zip

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <% Response.WriteFile("MyFile.html") %>
</div>
```

Or, if you've got them installed on your web server, try [server-side includes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

`<!-- #Include virtual="/MyFile.html" -->`

Comment: It error : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\Products\Spec\test.htm'.