# Set Html File as Email Body from Shared Folder

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I've been searching for over 3 hours how to set the body of an email from an html file from my  MVC3 Shared Folder. 
I actually don't want to use File.ReadAllText() because I don't know where the file will be when the Application is deployed on a server. It would be really great if someone could help me 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try `Action Mailer` ?

Comment: How will you know where the file will be on the server when it comes time to add it's content to your email? I would imagine that you would use something like server mappath to get it's location.

Comment: @PankajGarg I am pretty new to ASP.NET. Could you show me a little code example?

Comment: @nocturns2 That's actually the point. I dont know where the application will be stored on the windows server :/
That's why I need a virtual link or something like that so I could tell the email body to use the html template from the shared folder

Comment: @Superbyte - Check the step by step help here https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Comment: @PankajGarg Can MvcMailer be used for commercial purposes so the company can use it without paying anything for that package?
I haven't found anything on the page you have linked
Is MvcMailer the another way to set the mail body from an html template?

Comment: @Superbyte - Yes. It is free to use.

Comment: @Superbyte - the MvcMailer looks pretty interesting. But as for where your files are stored for your project, I'm sure they would be relative to your other project files (i.e., your image, script and style folder). You should be able to create a folder for your templates in your project and reference them at that path.

Comment: @nocturns2 I created a Email Template Folder in the Views folder. But I don't know how to get the content of the html templates into the mail. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I managed it :)
I just took these 2 lines of code from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264724/read-html-file-from-folder-and-put-its-content-into-block-of-web-site-using-asp?rq=1) post and now I am able to set the body of the mail from an html template. Does anybody know how I could achieve adding dynamically a username to my html template?